# Turning Pandas DataFrame into Histogram Using Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a Pandas DataFrame which has a two columns, pageviews and type:

```
    pageviews   type
0   48.0        original
1   1.0         licensed
2   181.0       licensed
...
```

I'm trying to create a histogram each for original and licensed.  Each histogram would (ideally) chart the number of occurrences in a given range for that particular type.  So the x-axis would be a range of pageviews and the y-axis would be the number of pageviews that fall within that range.

Any recs on how to do this?  I feel like it should be straightforward...

Thanks!

Comment: there are a few straight-forward ways of doing this. what have you tried and which documentation have you read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using your current dataframe: `df.hist(by='type')`

For example:

```
# Me recreating your dataframe
pageviews = np.random.randint(200, size=100)
types = np.random.choice(['original','licensed'], size=100)

df = pd.DataFrame({'pageviews': pageviews,'type':types})

# Code you need to create faceted histogram by type
df.hist(by='type')
```

[pandas.DataFrame.hist documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html)

Comment: If you can create the dataframe like `pageviews = np.random.randint(200, size=100);
types = np.random.choice(['original','licensed'], size=100);
df = pd.DataFrame({'pageviews': pageviews,'type':types})` it would be more understandable.

Comment: Oh, good point. I'll make that edit. I assume the OP does not need my setup code, but that's still a good fix.